# Show that $C/c \cong (c/(C^{op}))^{op}$.

Tags: category-theory

I'm working on problem 1.2.i in Emily Riehl's Category Theory in Context and got stuck. The problem is this:

> Show that $C/c \cong (c/(C^{op}))^{op}$.

A bijunction between the objects is faily simple, so I'll skip typing it. The issue I'm having is showing that the morphisms in one correspond to the morphisms in the other.

Let $f \in C(x, y)$, then $g \in C(c, x)$ and $h \in C(x, y)$. So $g,h \in C/c$ and $g^{op}, h^{op} \in (c/(C^{op}))^{op}$.

So by definition, $f^* \in Hom(C/c)$ iff $hf=g$

And also by definition, $f_* \in Hom((c/(C^{op}))^{op})$ iff $f^{op}g^{op} = h^{op}$.

So it seems like all I need to complete the proof is to show that $f^{op}g^{op} = h^{op} \Leftrightarrow hf = g$

But I can't figure out how to do that. Is it always the case commutativity in one category is preserved in the opposite category?

(I realize this may look like a homework question, but I'm working through the book on my own which is why I'm asking here.)

Comment: A morphism $f:g\rightarrow d$ in $C/c$ is a morphism such that $h\circ f=g$. A morphism $f^{op}:g^{op}\rightarrow h^{op}$ in $(c/C^{op})^{op}$ is a morphism $f^{op}:h^{op}\rightarrow g^{op}$ in $c/C^{op}$, so $$g^{op}=f^{op}\circ h^{op}=(h\circ f)^{op}$$ You just inverted the order in $c/C^{op}$

Comment: I don't understand the first line of your proof attempt. Please check it for typos and wrongly declared variables.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two objects in $\mathcal C/c$:

- $f : x \to c \in \mathcal C$
- $g : y \to c \in \mathcal C$

a map $m : f \to g \in \mathcal C/c$ is, by definition, a map $h : x \to y \in \mathcal C$ such that the triangle $f,g,h$ commutes.

---

Now take two objects from $(c / \mathcal C^{op})^{op}$:

- $f : c \to x \in \mathcal C^{op}$
- $g : c \to y \in \mathcal C^{op}$

and consider that a map $m : f \to g \in (c / \mathcal C^{op})^{op}$ is the same as a map $m : g \to f \in c / \mathcal C^{op}$ which is a map $h : y \to x \in \mathcal C^{op}$ such that the triangle $f,g,h$ commutes. These 3 maps are exactly the opposite maps in our first example. So the categories are not just isomorphic but equal.